# What sense makes medium_large_size_h => 0?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

WP Version 5.4.2
There is an image size definition of medium_large with size_w = 768 and size_h = 0 -
You can find it near line 530 of wp-admin/includes/schema.php:

```
// 4.4.0
'medium_large_size_w'             => 768,
'medium_large_size_h'             => 0,
```

I'm wondering what sense this definition makes?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it's eventually used as a parameter to `wp_constrain_dimensions` where '0' means 'no limit'.

It's only used directly in media.php:85

```
  } elseif ( 'medium_large' === $size ) {
    $max_width  = intval( get_option( 'medium_large_size_w' ) );
    $max_height = intval( get_option( 'medium_large_size_h' ) );

    if ( intval( $content_width ) > 0 ) {
      $max_width = min( intval( $content_width ), $max_width );
    }
```

$max_height then used at :135

```
return wp_constrain_dimensions( $width, $height, $max_width, $max_height );
```

Docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_constrain_dimensions/) show 0 means no limit

Comment: OK. That makes sense.